# What are some known match making algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

That is, given a set of people, each with given features, is there a well known algorithm that is successful at pairing up the most similar people.

Am I over thinking this, or is there some standardized way to go about implementing this?

Comment: Is this maybe a linear assignment problem?

Comment: Probably the most well-known is the [stable-marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), which has a simple solution; but it's really a specific instance of the more general problem of pairing-with-preferences.  I would not recommend it for an actual dating site :)

Comment: Awesome, this looks like a great place to start, if you add it as an answer and (maybe?) give some more detail, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward algorithm would be to take each trait, assign a match value (for boolean traits, 1 or 0), importance weight (possibly a global importance value times a per-user weight based on their own personal assigned importance of the trait), then sum the multiplications of trait value & weights. My guess is that dating sites would use an algorithm like this.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I am looking for some well known implementations.